# Разговор ни о чем

Tags: парадоксы

Разговор ни о чем — это не беседа о погоде, это обмен репликами, не несущими информации. Начинаться такой разговор с незнакомым вам лицом может так: "Господин [фамилия] могу я претендовать на ваше внимание?" — "А почему на мое?" — "А почему не на ваше?" Через некоторое время господин может сказать что-то вроде: "Может быть, поговорим о чем-нибудь?" — "Говорите, я слушаю". — "А вы что же, отвечать не будете?" — "Ну знаете!.. И слушать, и отвечать... Не слишком ли много вы хотите?" — "???"  Вы владеете искусством вести разговор ни о чем? Научите!

Comment: Собственно, вопрос сводится к тому, как быть, если собеседник ляпнет что-нибудь существенное, и как заставить его отвечать такими же бессмысленными репликами, если подыгрывать он не собирается.

Comment: -О чем же вы?
-Так я же только что изрёк..
-Не понял Вашего суждения
-Быть стало, повторить?
-Произойдёт ли толк?
-Не знаю. Не исключено.
-Вот уточните, потом и говорите.

Answer (score 2):

Пример
 - Здравствуйте!
 - Добрый день.
 - Собственно вот заглянул к Вам..
 - Да, видимо.
 - Впрочем, чего это я зашёл?
 - Господь бог Вас знает..
 - И то правда... Вы ведь не заняты?
 - Отнюдь.
 - Хоть это дай сюда. Вы скоро освободитесь ?
 - Дотоле неизвестно.
 - Досадно.
 - Вы так считаете?
 - Почему бы и нет?
 - Почём же мне знать..
 - И я в сомнении..
 - Стало быть зашли Вы не спроста?
 - Совершенно верно.
 - Цели - знамениты?
 - По крайне мере небезызвестны.
 - Благо тут порядок..
 - Недурно побеседовали. Составите мне завтра компаньона?
 - Славо дельцо, заходите.
 "Занавес".

Comment: Хааааааахахаха, класс!

Answer (score 1):

Разговор на остановке в ожидании автобуса маршрутом на дачи. "Говорят, в деревне теперь никто уже не живёт" - "А зачем там жить, если в магазине всё можно купить?" - "Да, но сначала это надо вырастить, чтобы потом купить!" - "Вы как будто с Луны свалились! Существуют Продуктовые Базы, куда завозятся продукты со всего света, а уж оттудова на машинах их развозят по магазинам" - "Вы думаете, что я настолько глупа, что не знаю этого?" - "Я о Ваших умственных способностях не осведомлена, но могу теперь догадываться" - "Да ты сама дура!!" - "От дуры слышу!!"

Answer (score 0):

«Разговор ни о чём» — вот так нужно характеризовать обыденную речь каждого — есть исключения, да — человека.

Разговор «ни о чём» не несёт никакого смысла, то есть из этого разговора вообще невозможно подчерпнуть что бы то ни было полезное.

Многие разговорные фразы — например, «Как дела?», «Привет!», «Здорово!», «Здравствуйте» — зачастую просто мешают нормальному разговору. Приветствовать собеседника, безусловно, нужно, но делать это следует единожды.